# Pandas report top-n in group and pivot

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, top-n

I am trying to summarise a  dataframe by grouping along a single dimension d1 and reporting summary statistics for each element of d1. In particular I am interested in the top n (index and values) for a number of metrics.
what I would like to produce is a row for each element of d1.

Say I have two dimensions d1, d2 and 4 metrics m1,m2,m3, m4

1) what is the suggested way of grouping by d1, and finding the top n d2 and metric value, for each of metrics  m1 - m4.

in Wes's book Python for Data Analysis he suggests (page 35)

```
def get_top1000(group):
 return group.sort_index(by='births', ascending=False)[:1000]
grouped = names.groupby(['year', 'sex'])
top1000 = grouped.apply(get_top1000)
```

Is that still the recommended way ( i am only interested in say top 5 d2 out of 1000s, and for multiple metrics)
2) Now next problem is that I want to to pivot the top 5 ( ie so I have one row for each element of d1)

so resulting data frame should look like this for dimensions d1,d2 and metric m1:
index d1 and columns for top  5 values of d2 and corresponding values of m1

d1 d2-1 d2-2 d2-3 d2-4 d2-5  m1-1 m1-2 m1-3 m1-4 m1-5

....

so to pivot I have to create the ranking along d2 (ie 1 to 5 - this is my columns field). This would be easy if I always had 5 entries, but occasionally there are fewer than 5 elements of d2 for a given value of d1.

so could someone suggest how to add ranking to the grouping, so that I have the correct column index to perform the pivoting

Comment: you really should illustrate your desired format better. include some fake data and your expected output

Answer (score 10):

I don't have any toy data to use or expected results to compare to, but I think you want the following:

```
N = 1000
names = my_fake_data_loader()
grouped = names.groupby(['year', 'sex'])
grouped.apply(lambda g: g.sort_index(by='births', ascending=False).head(N))
```

And that will give to the first 1000 elements of each group.