# Returning top n values for group/multiindex in Pandas

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I have a df that contains daily product and volume data:

```
date        product     volume
20160101    A           10
20160101    B           5
...
20160102    A           20
...
...
20160328    B           20
20160328    C           100
...
20160330    D           20
```

I've grouped it up by month via

```
df['yearmonth'] = df.date.astype(str).str[:6]
grouped = df.groupby(['yearmonth','product'])['Volume'].sum()
```

which gives me a Series of the form:

```
yearmonth   product 
201601      A       100
            B       90
            C       90
            D       85
            E       180
            F       50
            ...
201602      A       200
            C       120
            F       220
            G       40
            I       50
            ...
201603      B       120
            C       110
            D       110
            ...
```

I want to return the top n volume values per product per month. For example the top 3 values would return:

```
201601  A  100
        B   90
        C   90
        E   180
201602  A   200
        C   120
        F   220
201603  B   120
        C   110
        D   110
```

I can find some answers using `pd.IndexSlice` and `select` but they seem to act on the index alone.  I can't figure out how to sort the individual group's values

- [Pandas report top-n in group and pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26309178/pandas-report-top-n-in-group-and-pivot) (which is Wes's example in "Python for Data Analysis" too)
- [pandas multi index sort specific fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200897/pandas-multi-index-sort-specific-fields)
- [pandas: slice a MultiIndex by range of secondary index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389203/pandas-slice-a-multiindex-by-range-of-secondary-index)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`SeriesGroupBy.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html):

```
print (grouped.groupby(level='yearmonth').nlargest(3).reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
yearmonth  product
201601     E          180
           A          100
           B           90
201602     F          220
           A          200
           C          120
201603     B          120
           C          110
           D          110
Name: val, dtype: int64
```

Also you can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) for convert to `year-month` period:

```
print (df)
        date product  Volume
0   20160101       A      10
1   20160101       B       5
2   20160101       C      10
3   20160101       D       5
4   20160102       A      20
5   20160102       A      10
6   20160102       B       5
7   20160102       C      10
8   20160102       D       5
9   20160328       A      20
10  20160328       C     100
11  20160328       B      20
12  20160328       D      20
13  20160330       D      20
```

---

```
grouped = df.groupby([pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%Y%m%d').dt.to_period('M'),
                     'product'])['Volume'].sum()
print (grouped)
date     product
2016-01  A           40
         B           10
         C           20
         D           10
2016-03  A           20
         B           20
         C          100
         D           40
Name: Volume, dtype: int64

print (grouped.groupby(level='date').nlargest(3).reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
date     product
2016-01  A           40
         C           20
         B           10
2016-03  C          100
         D           40
         A           20
Name: Volume, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael! This does the trick.  I had seen `nlargest()` as well but couldn't get it working for what I wanted - I need to group the group.  Also, good shout on the datetime conversion too.

Comment: Also if want use your solution, creating column is not necessary - `grouped = df.groupby([ df.date.astype(str).str[:6],'product'])['Volume'].sum()`